# Do we have to advance to next level for auto-sell?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

When we click go advance to next level it appears all items not picked up are automatically sold and split with the group.

Does the same thing happen if we click go to tavern instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the same thing occurs when you go to the tavern instead. You will see a message saying that the additional mana is added to your bank just before you start loading the tavern.

Comment: just to add to this, if you lose a round and there are items/mana on the ground, it will be lost

Comment: what about if you "restart level"?